# odd output from char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I am currently writing a command line "parser" so to speak, and so far it has been working until I tried a few ways to add options/parameters.

```
void parser::nextCom() {

    cout << parser::prompt; // parser::prompt = "> "
    string com;
    getline(cin, com);

    char the_command[5]; //  i want this to store the command e.g. "go" given that go is a command
    for (int i = 0; i < com.size(); i++) {
        if (com[i] == ' ') break;
        else the_command[i] = com[i];
    }

    cout << the_command << endl;
}
```

The command is copied but some very unwanted characters show up when in print `the_command` to the console.

This is what I get if I pass "go north" as a command:

`goÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌØNi`

I am not too sure about char arrays in C++, but I don't know how I am getting this output. Any help at all will be appreciated. Any questions about the code or if you need more of my code, just comment, thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cout << the_command << endl;
```

When you print a `char` array like this, characters continue to be inserted until the null character `\0` is found in the string.

Before you start copying characters from `com` to `the_command`, the array is completely uninitialized. I'll represent these unknown characters with question marks (but of course, they're probably not actually question marks):

```
? ? ? ? ?
```

This means you have no idea what the values of the `char`s in the array will be. You then copy only the characters `g` and `o` from `the_command` into `com`, so your array now contains:

```
g o ? ? ?
```

So when you attempt to output this array, the output stream doesn't know when to stop. You need to make sure you insert an `\0` after the `o`. One way to do that would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < com.size(); i++) {
    if (com[i] == ' ') {
      the_command[i] = '\0';
      break;
    }
    else the_command[i] = com[i];
}
```

This will leave the array like so:

```
g o \0 ? ?
```

However, you'd be much better off just sticking to `std::string`. I don't want to think about the trouble you'll have with this array that could just be avoided. Here's how I would write your function:

```
void parser::nextCom() {
    std::cout << parser::prompt;

    std::string command_line, command;
    std::getline(cin, command_line);

    std::stringstream command_line_stream(command_line);
    command_line_stream >> command;

    if (command == "go") {
      std::string direction;
      command_line_stream >> direction;
      go(direction);
    }
}
```

Comment: i wanted to make get the command and use if statements or switch statement to determine which function to run

Comment: well you have a point that i'd have trouble with the char array, just wasn't sure how to seperate the command using a string, does string stream do that for me?

Comment: @PurityLake `std::stringstream` makes it easy. You could do it with a `std::string` too.

Comment: Why is is `std::stringstream` being used in place of `std::istringstream`?

Comment: @David Either will do. You're probably right that `std::istringstream` is more appropriate here.

Answer (score 3):

You're not null-terminating `the_command` after the last character is read. Or doing *any* bounds checking.

Please, use `std::string` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Change the code to:

```
if (com[i] == ' ')
{
   com[i] = '\0';
   break;
}
```

This will ensure there is a null terminator at the end of your char array. The reason you are seeing garbage is because `std::cout` will happily print characters until it sees a null terminator.

Answer (score 1):

this is because you have a buffer overflow in your code. you copied an indeterminate length string into a char[5] buffer... basically, your loop is copying as many bytes as determined by the input string, into past the end of the char[5] array, which is no longer null terminated, so "cout" is just reading until it finds null bytes.

Comment: the way I was looking at it was that the first command will be no bigger than 5 characters

Comment: Well, theoretically, `if (com[i] == ' ') break;` should prevent the buf overflow for the input `"go north"`. (The code itself is still unsafe of course as you can't guarantee that condition for all input you might receive.)

Comment: Nice catch, Either way though, the buffer isn't null terminated, causing cout to read too far.

Answer (score 1):

Basically `the_command[5]` contains garbage since is not initialized and doesn't contains the character terminator. You can clear it first, and you'll be fine

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)  {
    the_command[i] = 0; 
}
```