# Char array returns four times more data than expected

Tags: c++, arrays

Before I continue, here's the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char array[] = {'a','b','c'};
    cout << array << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My system:

> - VisualStudio 2019, default C++ settings
> - Using Debug build instead of release

When I run this code sample, I get something like this in my console output:

```
abcXXXXXXXXX
```

Those X's represent seemingly random characters. I know they're from existing values in memory at that address, but I don't understand why I'm getting 12 bytes back instead of the three from my array.

Now, I know that if I were doing this with ints which are four bytes long, maybe this would make sense but `sizeof(array)` returns three (ie. three bytes long, I know the `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]` trick.) And when I do try it with ints, I'm even more confused because I get some four-byte hex number instead (maybe a memory address?)

This may be some trivial question, I'm sorry, but I'm just trying to figure out why it behaves like this. No vectors please, I'm trying to stay as non-STL as possible here.

Comment: Thou shalt null terminate character arrays when printing as strings.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/181505/what-is-a-null-terminated-string

Comment: I know how nullbytes work, but it doesn't change the fact that there are only three bytes. If the compiler cares so much that I declare a size when creating the variable, why doesn't it juststop reading once it hits the end of that soft-buffer?

Comment: Try this:  `cout << array[0] << array[1] << array[2] << endl;`

Comment: @Akira while it's true that there is a known size of the array, the array _decays_ to a `char*` pointer when you pass it to`cout`, which is then expected to be a null-terminated C-style string. Also remember that C++ offers **zero** protection against reading an array out of bounds, and weird things can happen when you do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using cout to print the entire contents of a character array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371845/using-cout-to-print-the-entire-contents-of-a-character-array)

Comment: @Akira *I'm trying to stay as non-STL as possible here* -- That doesn't change the fact that `cout`, when encountering a `char *`, requires null termination.  A `std::vector<char>::data()` would show the same symptoms.  As a matter of fact, many aspects of C++, when a `char *` is given, uses the terminating null to "stop reading".  It isn't just `cout` that will have this issue.  Try to use `strlen` with your array -- same issue.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie technically it's not `cout` at all, it's an `operator<<` overload . The same issue would occur with other stream destinations.

Comment: @M.M I believe you are confirming PaukMcKenzie's point exactly

Comment: @GBlodgett in that link the person creates an uninitialized array and tries to output it, which is substantially different to this case

Comment: @alter igel Thanks, that's a better explanation that I was looking for, how it turns into a pointer instead.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. You can't add an additional question or change the existing one after you've received answers to it. If you have a new question, click the *Ask Question* button at the top of the page and ask it there. For more information, see the [help].

Comment: @M.M Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557138/odd-output-from-char-array) is a better dupe target?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cout` takes this `char` array and addresses it as a null-terminated string.

Since the terminating character in this array is not the null character (i.e., `char(0)`), it attempts to print until encountering the null character.

At this point, it attempts to read memory outside of the array which you have allocated, and technically, anything could happen.

For example, there can be different data in that memory every time the function is called, or the memory access operation may even be illegal, depending on the address where `array` was allocated at the time the function was called.

So the behavior of your program is generally considered undefined (or non-deterministic).

Comment: note that `undefined` is a stronger condition than non-deterministic. There can be programs that randomly produce different integer sequences for example, without being undefined.

Comment: @M.M: I believe that on a finite-state machine, there is no such thing as *true random*, i.e., even the behavior of `rand()` can be predicted if one knows the initial seed (and more generally, when one knows the current state of every transistor on the machine). So I think that *non-deterministic* here is in fact equivalent to what most people usually refer to as *undefined*.

Comment: "undefined" is a term defined by the standard to mean that the behaviour is not defined at all by the standard.  True randomness could be achieved by calling a hardware true randomness generator for example. (Which you can do in C++ of course, assuming the generator is made available for user code to call)

Comment: @goodvibration finite state machines are not Turing complete, and so can't generally run C++. Did you mean Turing machine?

Comment: @M.M: Well, I guess that it's more of a theoretical argument, but my point from the previous comment remains - if the hardware has a finite number of states then the random-generator output can be predicted, hence its behavior is deterministic.

Comment: @alterigel: I meant a machine with a finite number of transistors, hence a finite number of states which it can represent.

Comment: It could measure time between emissions of a radioactive isotope

Comment: @M.M: Given that the resolution of a timer is also finite, and that the initial mass of this isotope is known, that behavior can be predicted accurately as well.

Comment: No it can't. Only the distribution that the values approach can be predicted.